# Ubuntu Server image with predefined user and ssh key for mass deployment

Tags: server, system-installation, continuous-deployment

I need to deploy many systems with an ubuntu installation. I have an Ansible script that installs all the software I need, but before that I need to get ubuntu on these systems. So I want to create an image that automatically installs ubuntu with a specific user/password, ssh and one autorized ssh key in the .ssh folder.
I have got this working with Cubic. But I still have to set an user and other settings before installing. How do I get rid of this wizard before installing?

When I create an droplet on digitialOcean I can insert this cloud init thing, I kinda want something similar.

Comment: Does this help: [InstallCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a preseed file to pre-configure your user info.

```
# Locale
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us

# Clock
d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Pacific
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

# Users
d-i passwd/user-fullname string UseYours
d-i passwd/username string UseYours
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password UseYours/
#d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
#d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password [crypt 3]
#d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true
```

(Reference: https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/681179)

Ensure your preseed file is listed in the boot configurations (`file=/cdrom/...`). If you simply add to the existing preseed file, then it will already be referenced by the boot configurations.

Also, here is an [example Debian preseed file](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/example-preseed.txt) with other possible parameters, in case it's useful to you.